# Removing last n characters of string variables, where n is variable

Tags: python, dataframe

so I have a dataframe where I am trying to remove the last n characters from each string of a column. Normally, I would use the following code:

```
df['code_0'] = df.code_0.map(lambda x: str(x)[:-4])
```

Which would remove 4 characters. However, the number of characters that needs to be removed depends on a value in another column. So if I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'text': ["text that needs to be removed", "more text that needs to be removed"], 'number of characters to remove': [2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How can I remove only the last 2 characters from the first row and 4 characters from the second row?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda`:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x["text"][:-x["number of characters to remove"]], axis=1)
0       text that needs to be remov
1    more text that needs to be rem
```

Comment: why use lambda and apple when you can use the str method on a Series object

Comment: @gold_cy - Because `df["text"].str[:-df["number of characters to remove"]]` doesn't work.